# How do I extract from table function in R variables that have count equal to a number?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
> head(ct)
  .id x Freq
1 PT_HIGH 0 9650
2 PT_HIGH 1  544
3  C_HIGH 0 7698
4  C_HIGH 1 2496
5    EOB1 1 9351
6    EOB1 2  816
```

...

I can do table function in R on them like this:

```
> table(ct$.id)

  C_HIGH  C_SCORE  DCCT_DN     EOB1    EOB10    EOB11    EOB12    EOB13 
       2       15        2        2        2        2        2        2 
   EOB14    EOB15     EOB2     EOB3     EOB4     EOB5     EOB6     EOB7 
       2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2 
    EOB8     EOB9    EOC2L    EOC2R    EOC3L    EOC3R    EOC4L    EOC4R 
       2        2        2        2        3        3        3        3 
   EOC5L    EOC5R    EOCAL    EOCAR   EOCB1L   EOCB1R   EOCB2L   EOCB2R 
       3        3        2        2        1        1        1        1 
  EOCB3L   EOCB3R   EOCB4L   EOCB4R   EOCB5L   EOCB5R  PT_HIGH PT_SCORE 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        2       16 
  SUMAMP  SUMFOOT   SUMLEG 
       1        3        1
```

How can I output only variables that have count =2. So those variables would be: C_HIGH, DCCT_DN    ,EOB1, EOB10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option is using `subset`, e.g.,

```
> subset(names(v), v == 2)
[1] "b" "g" "i" "w"
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
v <- table(sample(letters, 50, replace = TRUE))
```